# Getting error while consuming webservices throgh SOAP body approach in java although i have set proxy authentication

Tags: web-services

Getting Error while consuming webservices in java through SOAP approach. Plz suggest, i am stuck in this for last 10 days. I am using this server for webservices `"http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx"`

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error 
opening socket: Connection timed out: connect;
targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening 
socket: Connection timed out: connect]
at org.apache.soap.transport.http.SOAPHTTPConnection.se(SOAPHTTPConnection.java:324)
 at org.apache.soap.rpc.Call.invoke(Call.java:205)
 at com.check.ClientNet.main(ClientNet.java:47)
```

My java code is :

```
package com.check;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.soap.*;
import org.apache.soap.encoding.SOAPMappingRegistry;
import org.apache.soap.rpc.*;
import org.apache.soap.encoding.soapenc.StringDeserializer; 
import org.apache.soap.util.xml.QName; 
import com.check.ProxyAuthenticator;

public class ClientNet {

  public static void main (String[] args) 
       throws Exception {

             Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("http.proxyHost", "10.136.236.30");
        properties.put("http.proxyPort", "8080");
        properties.put("http.proxyUser", "bnkishore");
        properties.put("http.proxyPassword","XXXX");
        Properties newprops = new Properties(properties);
        System.setProperties(newprops);
        String username = System.getProperty("http.proxyUser");
         String password = System.getProperty("http.proxyPassword");     
        if (username != null && !username.equals("")) {         
           Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuthenticator(username, password));                
        }      

    System.out.println("\n\nCalling the SOAP Server:\n\n");          
    //http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx
    URL url = new URL ("http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx");
    String CountryName = "India";
    Call call = new Call();    
    SOAPMappingRegistry soapMappingRegistry = new SOAPMappingRegistry(); 
    soapMappingRegistry.mapTypes(Constants.NS_URI_SOAP_ENC, new QName("http://www.webserviceX.NET", "globalweather"),null,null, new StringDeserializer());   
    call.setTargetObjectURI("http://www.webserviceX.NET");  
    call.setMethodName("GetCitiesByCountry");       
    call.setEncodingStyleURI(Constants.NS_URI_SOAP_ENC);
    Vector<Parameter> params = new Vector<Parameter>();
    params.addElement(new Parameter("CountryName", String.class, CountryName, null));   
    call.setParams (params);

    System.out.print("The SOAP Server says: ");

    Response resp = call.invoke(url, " ");

    if (resp.generatedFault()) {
      Fault fault = resp.getFault();
      System.out.println("\nOuch, the call failed: ");
      System.out.println("  Fault Code   = " + fault.getFaultCode());
      System.out.println("  Fault String = " + fault.getFaultString());
    } else {
      Parameter result = resp.getReturnValue();
      System.out.print(result.getValue());
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

}
```

And ProxyAuthencator code is :

```
package com.check;

import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

public class ProxyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    private String userName, passWord;

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(userName,passWord.toCharArray());       
    }

    public ProxyAuthenticator(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.passWord = password;
        getPasswordAuthentication();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a timeout, that means you client is not reaching the server. Check connectivity. For dealing with a proxy, additionally to your `ProxyAuthenticator` you need to add few system properties: `proxySet`, `proxyHost` and `proxyPort`. If you are using maven, you can do it in this way:

```
 mvn jetty:run -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=proxy.indra.es -DproxyPort=8080
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I think there is no connectivity problem actually i am getting the output from the server in REST(Http Post/Get) approach. But i have set the proxy port, host and also provide username and password. You can see in my code. Actually there is some proxy problem.

Comment: Try the variables name I wrote. For example: proxyHost instead http.proxyHost

Comment: Same error is coming. May be need to change some code for proxy authentication.

Comment: try whit this one:

package com.check;

import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

public class SimpleAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    private String username, password;

    public SimpleAuthenticator(String username, String password) {

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
}

Comment: i used this code to authenticate username and password by JVM .

Comment: Without using ProxyAuthenticator class,getting same error. So, plz try this code and see whether same error is coming from ur side and response. or provide some other approach to consume webservices through SOAP format.